# Contact email flood limit is per whole system(application) or user/ip based?

Tags: emails, configuration

I have a question with contact emails flood limit which is present in contact.settings.yml, the limit is going to for whole system(application-wide) or is it going to limit the number of emails per individual user or IP?

Comment: It is IP based as per the answer here https://www.drupal.org/project/forward/issues/3034829

Answer (score 0):

As you can see its number of emails a user  can send in an hour

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/contact/overview#controlling-repeat-submission-blocking-flood-control

```
You can specify the text to display on your site-wide contact page and you can optionally limit how many times a user can submit a contact form in an hour.
```

btw, its defaults that you can override per any contact form . for example :
`contact.settings.yml`

```
default_form: feedback
flood:
  limit: 5
  interval: 3600
user_default_enabled: true
```